# How do I work out which process/service/program is sending systemd dbus messages?

Tags: debian, systemd, systemd-journald, journalctl

Currently my systemd journal is filling up with messages of the form:

```
Feb 01 16:40:31 host systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call 
sender=:1.58666 destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org
/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get
cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
```

The only identifier seems to be the sender, which appears to change every few seconds (so I've failed at trying to map the sender to a PID), and this does not appear to happen on other systems on similar hardware or OS. Is there some way of identifying what is sending this messages (so that I can either stop that process/service/whatever or control the amount of messages sent).

Answer (score 2):

There is a mapping between a [unique connection name](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#term-unique-name) 
and process accessible through `busctl`.

If it remains stable for a few seconds you could try your luck in trying to catch it as it occurs.

```
journalctl -f | \
while read line ; do
        echo "$line" | grep "sender=:"
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
                busctl --no-pager | grep
        fi
done
```

(Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331309/shellscript-to-monitor-a-log-file-if-keyword-triggers-then-execute-a-command))